# Reporting Services Server Version For SSRS 2017?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

we are currently running SS 2008R2 on our report server in conjunction with VS 2008 SSRS reports, but are considering upgrading our reporting services ide to VS 2017 to take advantage of newer report features.  what will we have to consider to ensure we have a fully-functional end-to-end reporting setup?

Comment: This question is very broad and may be closed as unanswerable.  Are you only upgrading VS or are you upgrading the servers as well?

Comment: as it stands, at least for the foreseeable future, we will only be upgrading our version of VS.  it is this combination that has us concerned.  will we be able to produce reports that are still compatible with the current 2008R2 server?